# ReactJs key-error in rendering <option> dynamically for <select> input using map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

To practice ReactJS, I'm trying to develop a small application. I am unable to solve the key-error.

What I'm trying to do:

[image: app screenshot]

The Pokemon can be added to a collection which is created by the user. I created 2 components for this. One component renders all the Pokemon cards and the other component is a Pokemon card.

The components are as follows -

PokemonCards.js

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from "@emotion/core"
import tw from "twin.macro"
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard"

import { useEffect } from "react"

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { fetchPokemonNameUrl, selectorPokemon } from "./pokemonCardsSlice"

const PokemonCards = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const pokemonList = useSelector(selectorPokemon)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPokemonNameUrl())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <div tw="p-2">
      Pokemon Cards
      <section tw="grid grid-cols-1 gap-2">
        <ul>
          {pokemonList.map(poke => (
            <PokemonCard
              key={`key-${poke.id}`}
              pokemonId={poke.id}
              pokemonName={poke.name}
              pokemonType={poke.type}
              pokemonHeight={poke.height}
              pokemonWeight={poke.weight}
              pokemonBaseExperience={poke.baseExperience}
              pokemonSprite={poke.sprites}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PokemonCards
```

PokemonCard.js

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from "@emotion/core"
import tw from "twin.macro"

import { useState } from "react"
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { add, selectorCollection } from "../home/collectionSlice"

const PokemonCard = props => {
  const collection = useSelector(selectorCollection)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const [collectionInput, setCollectionInput] = useState("")

  const addPokemonToList = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(collectionInput)
  }

  const {
    pokemonId,
    pokemonName,
    pokemonType,
    pokemonHeight,
    pokemonWeight,
    pokemonBaseExperience,
    pokemonSprite,
  } = props

  return (
    <div tw="flex flex-row justify-around items-center bg-red-500 p-2 my-2 rounded">
      <div tw="">
        <img tw="bg-cover bg-center" alt={pokemonName} src={pokemonSprite} />
      </div>
      <div tw="mx-1">
        <p>{pokemonName}</p>
        <p>{pokemonType}</p>
        <p>{pokemonHeight}</p>
        <p>{pokemonWeight}</p>
        <p>{pokemonBaseExperience}</p>
      </div>
      <div tw="mx-1">
        <form onSubmit={addPokemonToList}>
          <label>
            Add Pokemon to collection <br />
            <select
              value={collectionInput}
              onChange={e => setCollectionInput(e.target.value)}
            >
              {collection.map(col => (
                <option key={`${pokemonId}-${col.name}`} value={col.name}>
                  {col.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
          <button type="submit" tw="bg-gray-300 p-1 rounded">
            add
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PokemonCard
```

Here's what my state looks like:

[image]

I've put unique keys for both:

1. Pokemon cards
2. `<option>` in the `<select>` input which is present inside each card.

If I comment out the `<form>` in PokemonCard.js, the warning goes away. Which means, the error lies in the creation of `<options>` for the `<select>` input using map().

Here's the [Github repo](https://github.com/theairbend3r/pokedex).

Comment: Check if your `poke.id` is unique for every items in the array

Comment: I've added my redux state here. Even though I'm fetching only 10 Pokemon, it's adding all those twice. I don't understand why it's happening twice. I've added the github repo, could you please take a look?

Comment: Please always use the preview window when asking questions here. There were five HTML tags (e.g. `<form>`) that had "disappeared" because they were not formatted. The renderer here does accept certain HTML elements, so if you don't want them to be rendered literally (and you don't) then you need to place them in backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your Github repo. Here's the problem

```
export const pokemonCardsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "pokemonCards",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    getData: (state, action) => {
      state.pokemonList.push(action.payload)
    },
  },
})
```

Here in reducer you `push` to the store. That's okay but you fetch data in a child component call `PokemonCards.js`. So every time this component re-render, your dispatcher called with the action and push pokemonList to the end of the store.

To solve the issue, you can either fetch pokemon list in App component, or you can filter payload in reducer and only push if it is not in the store

Comment: Aaah. I see. I've added a filter that checks if a id exists before pushing the pokemon to the state. But isn't this problematic? Because, new values are still being fetched every time I switch pages and return back to the explore page. 

And I could fetch the pokemons in the App component but then it doesn't really belong there right. It belongs to the `PokemonCards` component. 

I fetch the pokemons like this `useEffect(() => { dispatch(fetchPokemonNameUrl())}, [dispatch])`. What if I use `[]` with `useEffect()` instead of `[dispatch]`?

Comment: Or is it okay to fetch pokemon from the app component itself?

Comment: It's depend on what you try to do. If you have fixed size of pokemon items then in you component you can first get pokemon array from store and check array.length is greater than zero. If it is not > 0 meas, you still didn't fetched them so you dispatch now

Comment: Putting it in to App component is not actually a good idea if the application is going be expand

Comment: If you have 1000 - 10000 items in the array, you probably get them as chuncks, so in first render, which mean in the `useEffect()` you check if the store array has items. if items not in there, you can get items like I said above, Now if you scroll down, or click on next button of you pagination, you need to fetch new list and now you need to filter

Comment: Okay. I will eventually fetch only 150 (exact) Pokemon. There are two places I can  check for length of state before fetching the data. One is where I dispatch the action to fetch (with `useEffect`) and the second is in the `pokemonCardsSlice.js` where I define the action to fetch. I want to do it in the second way because that way, all the logic is in one place. The problem I now face is - how to access the state in this async function I use to perform `axios.get()`. The function name is `const fetchPokemonNameUrl` in the `pokemonCardsSlice.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

In react, `key` should be unique. So you can add an index with it to make it unique.

```js
{
  collection.map((col,index) => (
    <option key={`${pokemonId}-${col.name}-${index}`} value={col.name}>
      {col.name}
    </option>
  ))
}
```

Comment: I just added the global state info. Even though I'm fetching 10 Pokemon, 1 have 20 in my state. I think this is causing duplication of key-ids. I've added a link to the github repo, could please spare a few minutes and take a look?

Comment: So, the 10 pokemons are re-fetched everytime you visit the explore page. 

So, if you go to explore => then home => then back to explore, you'll 2 sets of each pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a key id in collection, then you can use it as a key of your options:

```
{collection.map(col => (
  <option key={`${col.id}-${col.name}`} value={col.name}>
     {col.name}
  </option>
))}
```

For a better way, use destructuring

```
{collection.map(({id, name}) => (
  <option key={`${id}-${name}`} value={name}>
     {col.name}
  </option>
))}
```

Comment: I just added the global state info. Even though I'm fetching 10 Pokemon, 1 have 20 in my state. I think this is causing duplication of key-ids. I've added a link to the github repo, could please spare a few minutes and take a look?